# Android File Manager with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, file-manager

I'm trying to implement a simple file manager with navigation drawer. I'm using custom listview for displaying the contents of SDcard. These are My files

**activity_main_drawer.xml (The main layout)**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#F3F3F4"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

**file_view.xml (this is used as a custom list view)**

```
    <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fd_Icon1"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip" >
</ImageView>    
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fd_Icon1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip">
</TextView>
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView02" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fd_Icon1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip">
</TextView>
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextViewDate" 
    android:id="@+id/TextViewDate" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip">
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] menuItems;

    private FileChooser filechooser;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);

        //Gets the path of external storage



        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        _initMenu();
        mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        Fragment fragment = new FileChooser();
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }

    private void _initMenu() {
        NsMenuAdapter mAdapter = new NsMenuAdapter(this);

        // Add Header
        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header);

        // Add first block

        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ns_menu_items);
        String[] menuItemsIcon = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon);

        int res = 0;
        for (String item : menuItems) {

            int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string",
                    this.getPackageName());
            int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon[res],
                    "drawable", this.getPackageName());

            NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
            if (res == 1)
                mItem.counter = 12; // it is just an example...
            if (res == 3)
                mItem.counter = 3; // it is just an example...
            mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
            res++;
        }

        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header2);

        //add second block

        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ns_menu_items);
        String[] menuItemsIcon1 = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon);

        int res1 = 0;
        for (String item : menuItems) {

            int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string",
                    this.getPackageName());
            int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon1[res1],
                    "drawable", this.getPackageName());

            NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
            if (res1 == 1)
                mItem.counter = 12; // it is just an example...
            if (res1 == 3)
                mItem.counter = 3; // it is just an example...
            mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
            res1++;
        }
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        if (mDrawerList != null)
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
        // view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_save).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        /*
         * The action bar home/up should open or close the drawer.
         * ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
         */
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle your other action bar items...
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /*
     * This is used to toggle the title on the action bar
     */
    private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

        public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,
                DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout) {
            super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                    R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_close));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_open));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    }

    /*
     * Action to be performed when clicking item on the drawer
     */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the
            // drawer
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            String text = "menu click... should be implemented";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // You should reset item counter
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }

    }


}
```

**FileChooser.java**

```
public class FileChooser extends Fragment{

    private File currentDir;
    public FileChooser() {};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_view, container, false);
        currentDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        FileList flist = new FileList();
        flist.fill(currentDir);
        return rootView;
    }
    /*
     * Method to fill the current layout with files and folders from the external directory
     * 
     * @params: Path for the SD Card
     */
    public class FileList extends ListActivity{
    private File currentDir;
    private FileArrayAdapter adapter;
    void fill(File f)
    {
        File[]dirs = f.listFiles(); 
         this.setTitle(f.getName());
         List<Item>dir = new ArrayList<Item>();
         List<Item>fls = new ArrayList<Item>();
         try{
             for(File ff: dirs)
             { 
                Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified()); 
                DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                String date_modify = formater.format(lastModDate);
                if(ff.isDirectory()){


                    File[] fbuf = ff.listFiles(); 
                    int buf = 0;
                    if(fbuf != null){ 
                        buf = fbuf.length;
                    } 
                    else buf = 0; 
                    String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                    if(buf == 0) num_item = num_item + " item";
                    else num_item = num_item + " items";

                    //String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                    dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(),num_item,date_modify,ff.getAbsolutePath(),"directory_icon")); 
                }
                else
                {

                    fls.add(new Item(ff.getName(),ff.length() + " Byte", date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(),"file_icon"));
                }
             }
         }catch(Exception e)
         {    

         }
         Collections.sort(dir);
         Collections.sort(fls);
         dir.addAll(fls);
         if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName()))
             dir.add(0,new Item("..","Parent Directory","",f.getParent(),"directory_up"));
         adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(FileList.this,R.layout.file_view,dir);
         this.setListAdapter(adapter); 
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Item o = adapter.getItem(position);
        if(o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_icon")||o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_up")){
                currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
                fill(currentDir);
        }
        else
        {
            onFileClick(o);
        }
    }
    private void onFileClick(Item o)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Folder Clicked: "+ currentDir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

**FileArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{

    private Context c;
    private int id;
    private List<Item>items;

    public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Item> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        c = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = objects;
    }
    public Item getItem(int i)
     {
         return items.get(i);
     }
     @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               View v = convertView;
               if (v == null) {
                   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                   v = vi.inflate(id, null);
               }

               /* create a new view of my layout and inflate it in the row */
            //convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

               final Item o = items.get(position);
               if (o != null) {
                       TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                       TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                       TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDate);
                       /* Take the ImageView from layout and set the city's image */
                        ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fd_Icon1);
                        String uri = "drawable/" + o.getImage();
                        int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());
                        Drawable image = c.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                        imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);

                       if(t1!=null)
                        t1.setText(o.getName());
                       if(t2!=null)
                            t2.setText(o.getData());
                       if(t3!=null)
                            t3.setText(o.getDate());

               }
               return v;
       }

}
```

**logcat**

```
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819): Process: it.gmariotti.android.example.navigationdrawer, PID: 8819
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.gmariotti.android.example.navigationdrawer/com.tdl.filemannavdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4531)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at com.tdl.filemannavdrawer.FileArrayAdapter.<init>(FileArrayAdapter.java:25)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at com.tdl.filemannavdrawer.FileChooser$FileList.fill(FileChooser.java:89)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at com.tdl.filemannavdrawer.FileChooser.onCreateView(FileChooser.java:35)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5252)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2149)
11-25 11:48:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8819):     ... 11 more
```

In the FileChooser.java, I've called the list() in OnCreate(). Is there something wrong in that implementation? Anybody has a working example of file manager with navigation drawer which I can refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I used ListFragment for FileChooser class and removed the inner class. Also used another listview.xml. 
Here is the modified code

```
public class FileChooser extends ListFragment{

    private File currentDir;
    private FileArrayAdapter adapter;

    public FileChooser() {};

    public static ListFragment newInstance(Context context) {
        FileChooser f = new FileChooser();

        return f;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
       currentDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());

        fill(currentDir);
        return rootView;
    }
    /*
     * Method to fill the current layout with files and folders from the external directory
     * 
     * @params: Path for the SD Card
     */

    void fill(File f)
    {
        File[]dirs = f.listFiles(); 
         //this.setTitle(f.getName());
         List<Item>dir = new ArrayList<Item>();
         List<Item>fls = new ArrayList<Item>();
         try{
             for(File ff: dirs)
             { 
                Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified()); 
                DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                String date_modify = formater.format(lastModDate);
                if(ff.isDirectory()){


                    File[] fbuf = ff.listFiles(); 
                    int buf = 0;
                    if(fbuf != null){ 
                        buf = fbuf.length;
                    } 
                    else buf = 0; 
                    String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                    if(buf == 0) num_item = num_item + " item";
                    else num_item = num_item + " items";

                    //String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                    dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(),num_item,date_modify,ff.getAbsolutePath(),"directory_icon")); 
                }
                else
                {

                    fls.add(new Item(ff.getName(),ff.length() + " Byte", date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(),"file_icon"));
                }
             }
         }catch(Exception e)
         {    

         }
         Collections.sort(dir);
         Collections.sort(fls);
         dir.addAll(fls);
         if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName()))
             dir.add(0,new Item("..","Parent Directory","",f.getParent(),"directory_up"));
         adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.file_view,dir);
         this.setListAdapter(adapter); 
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Item o = adapter.getItem(position);
        if(o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_icon")||o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_up")){
                currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
                fill(currentDir);
        }
        else
        {
            onFileClick(o);
        }
    }
    private void onFileClick(Item o)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Folder Clicked: "+ currentDir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my File Manager Code. I have used a simple dialog:-

```
package com.wysiwyg.main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.dev_task_197_keyboard_accesory.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FileExplore extends Activity {

    // Stores names of traversed directories
    ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Check if the first level of the directory structure is the one showing
    private Boolean firstLvl = true;

    private static final String TAG = "F_PATH";

    private Item[] fileList;
    private File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "");
    private String chosenFile;
    private static final int DIALOG_LOAD_FILE = 1000;

    ListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        loadFileList();

        showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
        Log.d(TAG, path.getAbsolutePath());

    }

    private void loadFileList() {
        try {
            path.mkdirs();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "unable to write on the sd card ");
        }

        // Checks whether path exists
        if (path.exists()) {
            FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                    File sel = new File(dir, filename);
                    // Filters based on whether the file is hidden or not
                    return (sel.isFile() || sel.isDirectory())
                            && !sel.isHidden();

                }
            };

            String[] fList = path.list(filter);
            fileList = new Item[fList.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
                fileList[i] = new Item(fList[i], R.drawable.file_icon);

                // Convert into file path
                File sel = new File(path, fList[i]);

                // Set drawables
                if (sel.isDirectory()) {
                    fileList[i].icon = R.drawable.directory_icon;
                    Log.d("DIRECTORY", fileList[i].file);
                } else {
                    Log.d("FILE", fileList[i].file);
                }
            }

            if (!firstLvl) {
                Item temp[] = new Item[fileList.length + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                    temp[i + 1] = fileList[i];
                }
                temp[0] = new Item("Up", R.drawable.directory_up);
                fileList = temp;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "path does not exist");
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1,
                fileList) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // creates view
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                // put the image on the text view
                textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                        fileList[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

                // add margin between image and text (support various screen
                // densities)
                int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

                return view;
            }
        };

    }

    private class Item {
        public String file;
        public int icon;

        public Item(String file, Integer icon) {
            this.file = file;
            this.icon = icon;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return file;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);

        if (fileList == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No files loaded");
            dialog = builder.create();
            return dialog;
        }

        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_LOAD_FILE:
            builder.setTitle("Choose your file");
            builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    chosenFile = fileList[which].file;
                    File sel = new File(path + "/" + chosenFile);
                    if (sel.isDirectory()) {
                        firstLvl = false;

                        // Adds chosen directory to list
                        str.add(chosenFile);
                        fileList = null;
                        path = new File(sel + "");

                        loadFileList();

                        removeDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                        showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                        Log.d(TAG, path.getAbsolutePath());

                    }

                    // Checks if 'up' was clicked
                    else if (chosenFile.equalsIgnoreCase("up") && !sel.exists()) {

                        // present directory removed from list
                        String s = str.remove(str.size() - 1);

                        // path modified to exclude present directory
                        path = new File(path.toString().substring(0,
                                path.toString().lastIndexOf(s)));
                        fileList = null;

                        // if there are no more directories in the list, then
                        // its the first level
                        if (str.isEmpty()) {
                            firstLvl = true;
                        }
                        loadFileList();

                        removeDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                        showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                        Log.d(TAG, path.getAbsolutePath());

                    }
                    // File picked
                    else {
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                        returnIntent.putExtra("file", path + "/" + chosenFile);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);        
                        finish();
                        // Perform action with file picked
                    }

                }
            });
            break;
        }
        dialog = builder.show();
        return dialog;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but my file manager code without the navigation drawer runs perfect. When I merge the two I was getting the error. Never mind now, I fixed it using ListFragment and have put the code for others to refer. Unable to mark it as answer for the next one hour.